# Differences between these two passive voice sentences

Tags: passive-voice

What is the differences between two passive voice sentences in terms of meaning? Which one is looking good or can be used?

1. They can always be shown the door again.
2. The door can be shown them again.

Comment: If you mean 'show someone the door' in the sense of 'ask them to leave', only the first one works. In the unlikely situation of literally giving someone the opportunity to look at a door, you could use the second!

Comment: It's similar to the fact that the coarse BrE usage ***He's taking the piss out of you*** (He's making fun of you) can't idiomatically be transformed into ***Piss is being taken out of you by him***, even though *syntactically* that's a perfectly valid transformation. Doubtless there are many other cases like this.

Comment: Thanks @KateBunting. But totally confused. Aren't both sentence done by someone? I could use passive voice so far but I feel like I didn't know what passive voice is up to now. For example aren't these sentences mean the same? 
"__They can be sent letter by someone.__"
and "__The letter was sent to them by someone.__"

Comment: I recall someone once facetiously saying something like *An old friend came round for a chat when I'd just made a bacon sandwich. **Much fat was chewed*** ("non-idiomatic" transformation of ***We chewed the fat = We had a good natter***).

Comment: Colin Fine's comment below explains it well. In cases where an idiom isn't involved, you can say, for example "I was sent a letter" or "A letter was sent to me".

Answer (score 1):

idiom: someone is shown the door

Ergo: They can always be shown the door again.

The second one does not work.

It is the people who are shown the door. It is not the door that is shown to them.

The door can be shown them again. would mean: They are buying a door and want to see it again.

Comment: wow, even our edits are oddly similar... I saw you beat me by 10 seconds - wasn't sure if I should delete or not? +1 either way

Comment: @TCooper As you like. Fyi, though, the Brits do use: show x [pronoun] again. :) [I did not dv you.]

Comment: I hadn't caught that in downton abbey or top gear yet XD I added a qualifier to my answer to make the regionality of it more clear, and from that perspective, I think both are worth keeping. - I just added that because I realized I hadn't given you or the asker any credit yet. Your brevity (imo) makes your answer better.

Comment: I don't understand why second one does not work. For example: "__The letter was sent to them by someone.__".  Is this sentence correct? If so, why the second one does not work.

Comment: @user123960 That's a whole new question, that is also fit for this website. Can't answer that in a comment though

Comment: @user123960, it doesn't work because _show someone the door_ is an idiom, and idioms are not always decomposable. As with most things in language, there is not necessarily any logic to this. _Kick the bucket_ is a (rather dated) idiom for _die_, but _the bucket was kicked by him_ is something that nobody would say except as a joke.

Comment: @ColinFine thanks. The second one, is it grammatically correct regardless of the meaning?

Comment: @user123960: it's grammatical for some speakers. I don't think I'd say it myself. Equally, I wouldn't say _The award was given him_.

Comment: What would you say instead of that?

Comment: No, I would not say those either. The award was given to him. The door was shown to them.

Comment: Are all three wrong? __The book was read.__, 
__The road was seen.__,
__The letter was sent.__
But passive voice, I had learned, was like this.

Comment: @user123960 I am adding to what Colin said. He would not say: The award was given him. Nor would I. I would say: The award was given **to him**.

Answer (score -1):

From an American English perspective:

*1.*, definitely.

*2.* would need to be "The door can be shown **to** them again."* - but that's still very unnatural sounding.

*1.* I assume is used as in "I don't care if Anthony and Susan are still mad about the seating arrangements. We kicked them out once before. They can always be shown the door again." Or, the usage in terms of "kicking someone out" / forcing them to leave. If it's meant to be a literal usage, neither is idiomatic.**

*I've been made aware that the "to" is entirely unnecessary in British English usage. It is very unnatural to an American speaker, although, I don't think the intended meaning would be lost
**Except maybe the rare case, i.e. a door store's sales floor

Comment: why a downvote?